# Перебрать многомерный массив

Tags: php

Помогите перебрать многомерный массив, никак не получается, завис над ним и все тут...

Получается 
первое вложение - документ
второе вложение - характеристики документа
третье вложение - дополнительные характеристики

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [document_type] => request
            [document_uid] => 
            [document_id] => 13241457
            [state] => accepted
            [produce_date] => 2019-01-26
            [create_date] => 2019-01-25 13:31:55
            [full_document_id] => K-13241457
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [document_type] => shipping
            [document_id] => 19-00091015353
            [document_uid] => 0xa13a511994c54be34b62cc71c89003e3
            [total_sum] => 503
            [services] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Перевозка автотранспортная
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Информирование о статусе и местонахождении груза
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Страховка
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Страховка срока
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Въезд на наш терминал-получатель
                        )

                )

            [create_date] => 2019-01-25 15:30:33
            [payer] => Array
                (
                    [access] => 
                    [is_physical] => 
                )

            [payment_link] => 
            [payment_state] => paid
        )

)
```

Comment: Может `array_walk_recursive`?

Comment: сделать то чего с ним хотите?

Comment: нужно вывести список документов с характеристиками, документ 1, дата, id и тд, документ 2, .... но у него еще доп характеристики...